# Sort table by second column :jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, tablesorter, tablerowsorter

I seen this example from another question, it uses plain javascript to sort a table by the first column, does anyone know how i would sort by the second column?.

Im on a mobile device at the moment so I cant post code, a js fiddle is in the comments showing the example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mLYch/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very simple sorting script, so take it as that ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mLYch/159/))

```
function sortTable(column, direction){
    column = column || 0;
    var tbl = document.getElementById("caltbl").tBodies[0];
    var store = [];
    for(var i=0, len=tbl.rows.length; i<len; i++){
        var row = tbl.rows[i];
        var sortnr = row.cells[column].textContent || row.cells[column].innerText;
        if (!isNaN(sortnr)) { sortnr = parseFloat(sortnr); }
        store.push([sortnr, row]);
    }
    store.sort(function(x,y){
        return x[0] > y[0] ? 1 : x[0] < y[0] ? -1 : 0;
    });
    // look for "d" (descending) in the direction to switch sort direction
    if (direction && /d/.test(direction)) { store.reverse(); }
    for(var i=0, len=store.length; i<len; i++){
        tbl.appendChild(store[i][1]);
    }
    store = null;
}
```